# Why do we use function prototypes?

Tags: c++, function

I'm working with functions for the first time, and I'm curious as to why
we use function prototypes. Why do we use them? Do we need to use them>

Comment: There are no "function prototypes" in C++. That's a C concept. C is weird.

Comment: @KerrekSB Function declarations in C++ could be described as prototypes.

Comment: In C++ I think the main reason is type safety. The compiler can't check the types you're passing to a function if it doesn't know how the function is defined.

Comment: If you decide to go into hooking functions, you need to know the function signature and a `typedef` really helps.. that way you can call the original function easily without having to cast all the time.

Comment: They are used so that we can break a program down into separate files and distribute them as binaries to be linked in with other programs. They tell the compiler how to access the already compiled binaries.

Comment: @KerrekSB The C++11 standard refers to "function prototypes".

Comment: Why would you *not* use function prototypes? What alternative do you have in mind?

Comment: @KerrekSB: The 1998, 2003, and 2011 C++ standards all refer to "function prototypes". What C has that C++ lacks is function declarations that *aren't* prototypes.

Comment: @KeithThompson: one alternative to function prototypes as an abstract view of a class definition, could be something like Eiffel's short tool, generating an abstract view automatically from the full source code. one alternative for a recursive set of functions is to nest them, function definitions inside functions. in c++ that's easy, via classes in C++03 and now via lambdas in C++11, but not in C.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Sure -- but I was hoping for a response from the OP that would make it clearer just what he's asking.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Hm, the word appears a very small number of times and never in anything resembling a definition. It seems to me that that's an editorial remnant that shouldn't be there. Let's see if it survives to C++17 :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a difference between absolute need and in-practice need. Technically we do not need the language's loop constructs `for`, `do` and `while`, they're completely superfluous. Practically it's different, you would not want to be reduced to using `goto` and `longjmp`.

Technically propotypes are only needed for recursive functions, and for use of function pointers.

In practice, you need them as means to partition larger source code into manageable chunks, modules, and as a more astract view of things.

---

One alternative to function prototypes as an abstract view of a class definition, could be something like [Eiffel's short tool](http://efsa.sourceforge.net/archive/wilson/tool.htm), generating an abstract view automatically from the full source code. One alternative for a recursive set of functions is to nest them, function definitions inside functions. In c++ that's easy, via local classes in C++03 and now via lambdas in C++11, but not in C.

Comment: Sorry for posting this answer originally without mentioning function pointers. Don't know why that didn't appear in my mind. Anyway, now fixed, apparently before anyone noticed! :-)